# Apache mirroring folder

Tags: php, apache, webserver

So I have a PHP system over an Apache Server running on a Window SO.
I want to create some kind of a mirror of it to make tests and whatever without have to copy the source code. For example: Actual scenario:

> `http://192.168.1.1/finantial` lies on C:\EasyPHP\www\finantial

I want to create this:

> `http://192.168.1.1/finantial_test` that points to the same source code
>   that the address above.

When this configs were ok, I can make the app to use different database.

Comment: create a virtualhost pointing to the same directory, or a redirect

Comment: @GeoPhoenix the user will browse system under /finantial_test but he will running /finantial indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so easy to do that. Just add an `Alias` to your `VirtualHost` like...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /finantial_test "C:/EasyPHP/www/finantial"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

on real server the configuration should be like this

test_financial.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/financial
ServerName test.financial.com
</VirtualHost>
```

financial.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/financial
ServerName financial.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It have to be on an .htaccess or it can be done on apache.conf ?

Comment: in windows i think its in apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf , in my answer i added two separate VirtualHosts because i thought you can make more out of it, like require authentication to access the test.financial.

Comment: thank you but I resolved my problem with Alias as describe on my own ansert above.